# application of power of a point and ptolemy's theorem

Tags: geometry

Let ABC be a triangle with side lengths $AB = 24, CA = 34, BC = 50$. Call the circle with diameter $BC$ ω with O as the center. Let $BA$ intersect $ω$ at $D$ ($D \ne B$) and $CA$ intersect ω at $E$ ($E\ne C$). Let the reflection of $D$ over $O $be defined as $D'$, and have $OA$ and $D'E$ intersect at $F$. Let$ G$ be a point on segment $BC$ such that $CD = 7BG$. Find the length of segment $FG$.

So I have tried to use power of a point with Ptolemy's theorem but doesn't find it works well since there aren't really enough info... Any help on how to do this will be greatly appreciated

EDIT: apparently this problem is really complex (all long geometry problem is complex when there isn't similar triangle! jk) So the simplest way is to use law of sine+cosine, property of cyclic quadrilaterals? Is there another solution to this with less intuition/ calculation? I just think I could never think about adding of point f' which the solution did :(

Comment: * *Application*

Comment: Under what circumstances you can apply the power of a point? Is it because  FB is tangent to BDCD'?

Comment: oh I mean I am applying power of a point at the beginning to get $AE/AD=17/12$ and I tried to use Ptolemy's theorem on both BDCD' and BDCE but they don't work

Comment: Have you ever thought of $\angle FBO = 90^0$?. If that is true, the whole problem can be solved.

Comment: wait how do you get there? is it by angle chasing?

Comment: Geogebra verified that is the case. I am still trying to prove that is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a scheme of the solution.

1. By the cosine rule you can find angles $\angle ABC$ and $\angle ACB$:
   $$
   \cos(\angle ABC)={4\over5},\quad \sin(\angle ABC)={3\over5},\quad
   \cos(\angle ACB)={154\over170},\quad \sin(\angle ACB)={72\over170}.
   $$
2. From that you get $CD=BD'=30$.
3. Let $F'$ be the point where line $ED'$ meets the tangent at $B$, and apply the sine rule to triangle $BD'F'$. By taking into account that 
   $\angle BD'F'=\angle BCA$ and $\angle F'BD'=\pi/2+\angle DCB=\pi-\angle ABC$, one gets: $\displaystyle BF'={1800\over29}$.
4. By the cosine rule applied to $BAO$ you can first compute $OA=\sqrt{241}$ and then find $\cos\angle BOA$, from which one obtains 
   $\displaystyle \tan\angle BOA={72\over29}$.
5. But we also have $\displaystyle {BF'\over OB}={72\over29}$, hence line $OA$ intersects tangent $BF'$ at $F'$, and $F'=F$.
6. Now you know $BF={1800\over29}$ and $BG={30\over7}$, thus you can find $FG$ by Pythagoras' theorem.

[image]

EDIT.

Notice that $OA$ and $D'E$ meet on the line tangent at $B$ not only in this case, but for any position of point $A$ inside the circle of diameter $BC$. I don't know, however, a simple proof for that.

Comment: wait i think cos(abc) should be 4/5 though

Comment: Right, thank you: corrected now.

Comment: and do you mean sinACB= 72/170 instead of sinABC=72/170?

Comment: Yes, of course: just another typo.

Comment: and can you just show how do you arrive at CD=BD'=30? I tried law of sines but it doesm't work.

Comment: Triangle $BCD$ is right, so: $CD=BC\sin(\angle CDB)$.

Comment: oh yeah forgot that! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

It looks that Stewart’s Theorem is useful here.

[image]

It states that in $\triangle ABC$
\begin{align}
a^2\,n+b^2\,m&=c\,(d^2+m\,n)
.
\end{align}

[image]

Fist, some helpful properties precalculated:
\begin{align}
S_{ABC}&=360
,\quad
\sin\alpha=\tfrac{15}{17} 
,\quad
\sin\beta=\tfrac35 
,\quad
\sin\gamma=\tfrac{36}{85} 
,\quad \cos\beta=\tfrac45
,\quad \cos\gamma=\tfrac{77}{85}
,\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
 |CD|&=|BC|\,\sin\beta
 =30
 ,\\
    |BG|&=\tfrac17|CD|=\tfrac{30}7
 ,\\
 |OG|&=\tfrac12|BC|-|BG|=\tfrac{145}{7}
 ,\\
 |BE|&=|BC|\,\sin\gamma
 =\tfrac{360}{17}
 ,\\
 |BD|&=|BC|\cos\beta=40
 ,\\
 |CE|&=|BC|\cos\gamma=\tfrac{770}{17}
 ,\\
 |AE|&=|CE|-|AC|=\tfrac{192}{17}
 ,\\
 \angle ED'D
 &=\tfrac\pi2-\beta-\gamma
 ,\\
 |DE|&=|BC|\,\sin\angle ED'D
 \\
 &=|BC|\,\sin(\tfrac\pi2-\beta-\gamma)
 \\
 &=|BC|\,\cos(\beta+\gamma)
 \\
 &=|BC|\,(\cos\beta\cos\gamma-\sin\beta\sin\gamma)
 \\
 &=|BC|\,\left(\sqrt{(1-\sin^2\beta)(1-\sin^2\gamma)}-\sin\beta\sin\gamma\right)
 \\
 &=|BC|\,\tfrac8{17}
 =\tfrac{400}{17}
 ,\\
 |D'E|&=\sqrt{|BC|^2-|DE^2|}
 =\tfrac{750}{17}
 ,\\
\end{align}

According to  Stewart’s Theorem, in $\triangle ABC$

\begin{align}
|OA|&=
\sqrt{\tfrac12(|AB|^2+|AC|^2)-\tfrac14|BC|^2}
=\sqrt{241}
,\\
|AM|&=25-\sqrt{241}
.
\end{align}

According to  Stewart’s Theorem, in $\triangle OME$

\begin{align}
|EM|&=
\sqrt{\frac{|OM|(|AE|^2+|OA||AM|)-|OE|^2|AM|}{|OA|}}
=\tfrac5{4097}\sqrt{839270450-51431810\sqrt{241}}
.
\end{align}

According to  Stewart’s Theorem, in $\triangle ODM$

\begin{align}
|MD|&=
\sqrt{\frac{|OM|\,(|AD|^2+|OA|\,|AM|)-|OD|^2|AM|}{|OA|}}
=\tfrac5{241}\sqrt{2904050-147010\sqrt{241}}
.
\end{align}

According to  Stewart’s Theorem, in $\triangle BOM$

\begin{align}
|BM|&=
\sqrt{\frac{\tfrac12|BC|(|AB|^2+|OA|\,|AM|)-1/4*BC^2*AM}{|OA|}}
=\tfrac5{241}\sqrt{2904050-69890\sqrt{24}}
.
\end{align}

Also,
\begin{align}
\cos\angle BOM&=
1-2\sin^2\tfrac12\angle BOM
=1-2\left(\frac{|BM|}{|BC|}\right)^2
=\tfrac{29}{1205}\sqrt{241}
.
\end{align}

According to the power of a point $F$,

\begin{align}
\frac{|EF|}{|NF|}
&=
\frac{|MF|}{|D'F|}
=k
\tag{1}\label{1}
,
\end{align}

hence $\triangle MFE \sim \triangle D'FN$
and 
\begin{align}
k&
=\frac{|EM|}{|D'N|}
=\frac{|EM|}{|MD|}
=\tfrac5{102}\sqrt{241}-\tfrac{29}{102}
.
\end{align}

Now \eqref{1} can be rewritten as a system of two equations in two
unknowns, $|EF|$ and $MF$:

\begin{align}
 \frac{|EF|}{|MF|+|BC|}
 &=k
,\\
\frac{|MF|}{|EF|+|D'E|}&=k
,
\end{align}

it follows that 
\begin{align}
|MF|&=
\frac{k\,(k\,|BC|+|D'E|)}{1-k^2}
=\tfrac{125}{29}\sqrt{241}-25
,\\
|EF|&=
\frac{k\,(k\,|D'E|+|BC|)}{1-k^2}
=\tfrac{21600}{493}
,\\
|OF|&=|MF|+\tfrac12|BC|=\tfrac{125}{29}\sqrt{241}
.
\end{align}

Finally, from $\triangle FGO$,
\begin{align} 
|FG|&=
\sqrt{
|OG|^2+|OF|^2-2|OG|\,|OF|\cos\angle BOA
}
=\frac{12630}{203}
.
\end{align}

As a bonus,
\begin{align} 
|BF|^2&=
\tfrac14|BC|^2+|OF|^2-|BC|\,|OF|\cos\angle BOA
=\tfrac{3240000}{841}
,\\
|FG|^2-|BG|^2
&=\tfrac{3240000}{841}
,
\end{align}

so, indeed, $BF\perp BC$.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mick suggests in a comment, once you know $\overline{FB}\perp\overline{BC}$, the problem is solved, so I'll just prove that. However, instead of constructing $F$ and showing the perpendicularity property, I'll construct the perpendicular at $B$ and show that it concurs with $\overleftrightarrow{OA}$ and $\overrightarrow{D^\prime E}$, via [the trigonometric form of Ceva's Theorem](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/TrigCeva.shtml).

---

Consider $\triangle ABE$ in the figure:

[image]

In order to name relevant angles, define $A^\prime$ on $\overleftrightarrow{OA}$, $E^\prime$ on $\overleftrightarrow{D^\prime E}$, and $B^\prime$ on the perpendicular to $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$ at $B$, such that $\overrightarrow{AA^\prime}$, $\overrightarrow{BB^\prime}$, $\overrightarrow{EE^\prime}$ are directed toward the ostensible point of concurrency. (Note: Our diagram and argument assume that $\angle A$ is obtuse; equivalently, that $A$ is inside the circle. The reader is invited to make appropriate adjustments for the acute case, where $A$ is outside the circle.)

That concurrency is guaranteed if we can show
$$
\frac{\sin\angle A^\prime AE}{\sin\angle A^\prime AB} \;
\frac{\sin\angle B^\prime BA}{\sin\angle B^\prime BE} \; 
\frac{\sin\angle E^\prime EB}{\sin\angle E^\prime EA} = 1 \tag{1}$$

Well, consider the following (where I'll write $\angle B$ and $\angle C$ for the angles at those vertices in $\triangle ABC$) ...

- $\angle B^\prime BA = 90^\circ - \angle B$, clearly. So, $\sin\angle B^\prime BA = \cos B$.
- $\angle B^\prime B E = \angle C$, as inscribed angles subtending $\stackrel{\frown}{BE}$. So, $\sin\angle B^\prime BE = \sin C$.
- $\angle E^\prime E B = 180^\circ - \angle B$. This follows from the fact that $\angle BED^\prime \cong \angle B$ as inscribed angles subtending congruent arcs $\stackrel{\frown}{CD}$ and $\stackrel{\frown}{BD^\prime}$. So $\sin \angle E^\prime E B = \sin B$.
- $\angle E^\prime EA = 90^\circ +\angle B$. This follows from the additional fact that, by [Thales's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27_theorem), $\angle BEC$ is a right angle. So $\sin \angle E^\prime EA = \cos B$.

Consequently, the left-hand-side of $(1)$ reduces to

$$
\frac{\sin\angle A^\prime AE}{\sin\angle A^\prime AB} \;
\frac{\cos B}{\sin C} \; 
\frac{\sin B}{\cos B} \qquad\to\qquad
\frac{\sin\angle A^\prime AE}{\sin\angle A^\prime AB} \;
\frac{\sin B}{\sin C}
 \tag{2}$$

Now, observe that $\angle A^\prime A B$ is the supplement of $\angle OAB$, whereas $\angle A^\prime AE \cong \angle OAC$. Therefore, $(2)$ becomes
$$\frac{\sin\angle OAC}{\sin C} \;
\frac{\sin B}{\sin\angle OAB}
 \tag{3}$$

where we've arranged the elements in anticipation of invoking the [Law of Sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) in $\triangle OAB$ and $\triangle OAC$.

$$\frac{|\overline{OC}|}{|\overline{OA}|} \;
\frac{|\overline{OA}|}{|\overline{OB}|} \qquad\to\qquad 1
 \tag{4}$$

Thus, the relation is proven, and Ceva guarantees that the perpendicular at $B$ meets the point of intersection ($F$) of $\overleftrightarrow{OA}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{D^\prime E}$, as claimed. $\square$

Comment: wait will Pascal's theorem give us the concurrency immediately?

Comment: @Guywhofailedeverything: I'm not seeing it.